# Display image inside svg

Tags: html, xml, image, svg, xslt

I want to place an PNG image inside the middle of a svg circle in a simple html file. Still i want a light-green background color of the circle and the image should not fill the whole circle.
How do i do that?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve, which components you have and how you want to combine them. Do you have a raster image like a GIF or PNG or JPEG when you mention a base64 image? You say you want an orange background color to the circle but show one with a lightgreen background.

Comment: Is the size of the PNG known?

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question to add the SVG code of what you tried, and which (wrong) result you get. We already know what you want to get.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking what the final SVG code should look like in order to render as shown? If so, the question is about SVG and not about XSLT (at least not yet). If you do know what the result should be then add it to your question.

Comment: Rolled back your edit, which totally obliterated your question only to declare that your question was answered.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the clip path is needed for, in the end you just need to position the circle, the text and the image as needed e.g.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="490" fill="lightgreen" stroke="green" stroke-width="3px"/>
  <image x="375" y="375" width="250" height="250" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,iVBORw[snip]"/>
  <text x="400" y="820" font-size="80">60/min</text>
</svg>
```

In the end it might be better to group all three items as a symbol:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="circle-text-image1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle cx="500" cy="500" r="490" fill="lightgreen" stroke="green" stroke-width="3px"/>
  <image x="375" y="375" width="250" height="250" xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,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"/>
  <text x="400" y="820" font-size="80">60/min</text>    
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle-text-image1" x="50" y="50"/>
</svg>
```

Only the second snippet has your full image data as otherwise the answer would exceed the StackOverflow limits.

Comment: You can reuse a symbol but not a group (`g` element); and I find it easier with the `symbol` where you can set up your dimensions and your viewBox to then position the items making up the symbol in that area while with a `g` element I think you have to translate/scale.